Android Studio - Double tooltip when hovering over classes in flutter
I updated Android Studio to Koala 2024.1.1

and now, everytime I hover over a class, I get 2 tooltips. The first one:

which is the one i want.
In less then 1 second, though, it gets replaced with a second one which I don't want:

Is there a solution? Is this a known bug or is it maybe caused by something else like my plugins? Thanks for any help

have you found solution?

The highly bothering issue come from Debugger, you can uncheck the following setting to solve this :
Build, Execution, Deployment, Debugger, Data Views, Show value tooltip.

